# Adding monomials of different degree.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Can you prove that x^m + x^n can never equal x^k, where k is some rational number, and m is not equal to n.

I know we've all been doing it since middle school, but is there a mathematical way of proving it?

Comment: What happens when you plug in 1 into both equations?

Comment: @Joel nothing of note; $1+1\neq 1$

Comment: @Sidd presumably we are to assume $x \neq 0$.  Any further restrictions?

Comment: @omnomnomnom This means that you can't write $x^k$ as $x^m+x^n$, since the two expressions dont agree at $x=1$.

Comment: @Joel: You're interpreting it as them never being equal for _all_ $x$, we're interpreting it as never being equal for _any_ $x$. Sidd, can you clarify the intention?

Comment: @Semiclassical: I mean that there cannot be any continuous interval in which the equality holds.

Comment: What I am looking for is an algebraic proof. For example, right now I was working on linear independence, and was able to prove that the equality holds only when k equals m or n.

Comment: Thanks a lot Semiclassical, Omnomnomnom, Matt B. and Joel. I got my answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, note that there will be trivial solutions; indeed, if $m\leq n$ then there will be $m$ of them. We can eliminate these by dividing out $x^m$, so the only case we really need concern ourselves with is $1+x^n = x^k$.

But this certainly has solutions. For example, $x^2=1+x$ includes the golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$ as an irrational solution. A better question is what *kinds* of solutions one gets: must they always be irrational?

Answer (score 1):

$x=0$ is trivial and works. If $x \not = 0$, necessarily $k>max(n,m)$ so let's suppose $m<n<k$. Then you're trying to solve $x^k - x^n - x^m = 0 \Leftrightarrow x^m(x^{k-m}-x^{n-m}-1)=0 \Leftrightarrow (x^{k-m}-x^{n-m}-1)=0$ which is a perfectly valid expression that has roots and everything depending on the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I did it. I wrote down the equality, and calculated the Wronskian for the expression, assuming x^m, x^n and x^k to be all functions. The Wronskian comes out to be non-zero if k is any value other than either m or n. Hence proving that the three terms are linearly independent, and hence, no equality exists for k not equal to m or n.

Glad to see that there are easier ways as well, and also learnt to watch out for trivial solutions after reading the other responses.